# Creating MYSQL Procedure in Laravel 4 Migrations

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, laravel, laravel-4, database-migration

Is there a way to generate stored MYSQL procedures in a Laravel 4 migration?

For example, here's a simple procedure generation query stored as a string (via a [Heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc))

```
    $query = <<<SQL
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test$$
CREATE PROCEDURE test()
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `test_table`(`name`) VALUES('test');
END$$
DELIMITER ;
SQL;

    DB:statement(DB::RAW($query));
```

---

When Running this in a migration's `up()` function I get this error:

[image]

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There are two major problems with your code

1. `DELIMITER` is not a valid sql statement. It's just a MySql client command. So just don't use it. *BTW* the error you get tells you exactly that.
2. You can't use `DB::statement` to execute `CREATE PROCEDURE` code because it uses prepared statement [source code for `Connection`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php#L322-L332). You can use PDO [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php) `DB::connection()->getPdo()->exec()` instead

That being said a sample migration for imaginary `tags` table might look like this

```php
class CreateTagsTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tags', function($table){
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name')->unique();
        });
$sql = <<<SQL
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_insert_tag;
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_insert_tag(IN _name VARCHAR(32))
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `tags`(`name`) VALUES(_name);
END
SQL;
        DB::connection()->getPdo()->exec($sql);
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        $sql = "DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_insert_tag";
        DB::connection()->getPdo()->exec($sql);
        Schema::drop('tags');
    }
}
```

Comment: Just wanted to mention, someone on the Laravel forums pointed out that you don't even need to use the PDO object, you can just call `DB::unprepared($sql)` and it will work just as well. Sure it probably boils down to the same thing in the end, but less code :)

Answer (score 13):

For fellow dev looking for the link in laravel mentioned by @Johannes.

[Any way to create MYSQL Procedures in Migrations?](http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=12051) answered by @aheissenberger.

I use this and it works well for me:

```
public function up() {            
    DB::unprepared('CREATE PROCEDURE get_highscore() BEGIN SET time_zone = \'Europe/Berlin\'; SET @refscore :=0; SELECT * FROM test; END');
}

public function down() {
    DB::unprepared('DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS get_highscore');
}
```

To call a procedure in your code:

```
DB::unprepared('CALL get_highscore()');
```

if you expect a resulting table:

```
DB::statement('CALL update_highscore()');
```

if you expect variables:

```
DB::statement('CALL update_ranking(3,10,@olduser,@newuser)');
$dberg = DB::select('select @olduser as old, @newuser as new');
```