# Laravel Migration DELIMITER

Tags: mysql, migration, database-migration, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I'm trying to create a MySQL trigger via artisan migration.

```
DB::unprepared('
    DELIMITER $$
    CREATE TRIGGER cascade_courseAffinity_after_facultyAffinity
    AFTER DELETE ON faculty_affinities
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        DELETE ca
        FROM course_affinities AS ca
        JOIN courses AS course1 ON ca.course1_id = course1.id 
        JOIN courses AS course2 ON ca.course2_id = course2.id    
        WHERE (course1.faculty_id = OLD.faculty1_id OR course1.faculty_id = OLD.faculty2_id)
        AND (course2.faculty_id = OLD.faculty1_id OR course2.faculty_id = OLD.faculty2_id);
        END
    $$
');
```

Nevertheless when I run the migration, I get the error

```
SQLSTATE[]: Syntax error... near DELIMITER $$ at line 1
```

Help someone?

Edit 1: this are the migration files i'm using on MySQL

Create the "courses" table with the one to many relationship to faculty (faculty_id).

```
Schema::create('courses', function (Blueprint $table) {
                    $table->increments('id');
                    $table->string('name', 150);
                    $table->integer('faculty_id')->unsigned();
                    $table->foreign('faculty_id')->references('id')->on('faculties');
                    $table->boolean('active')->default(1);
                    //$table->softDeletes();
                });
```

Create the "faculties" table.

```
        Schema::create('faculties', function (Blueprint $table) {
                        $table->increments('id');
                        $table->string('name', 150)->unique();
                        $table->boolean('active')->default(1);
                        //$table->softDeletes();
                });
```

Create the "course_affinities" table with the many to many relationship self relationship between courses.

```
    Schema::create('course_affinities', function (Blueprint $table) {
                    $table->increments('id');
                    $table->integer('course1_id')->unsigned();
                        $table->foreign('course1_id')->references('id')->on('courses');
                    $table->integer('course2_id')->unsigned();
                        $table->foreign('course2_id')->references('id')->on('courses');
                    $table->boolean('active')->default(1);
                    //$table->softDeletes();
                });
```

Create the "faculty_affinities" table with the many to many relationship self relationship between faculties.

```
    Schema::create('faculty_affinities', function (Blueprint $table) {
                    $table->increments('id');
                    $table->integer('faculty1_id')->unsigned();
                        $table->foreign('faculty1_id')->references('id')->on('faculties');
                    $table->integer('faculty2_id')->unsigned();
                        $table->foreign('faculty2_id')->references('id')->on('faculties');
                    $table->boolean('active')->default(1);
                    //$table->softDeletes();
                });
```

Comment: Did you generate any migration file?

Comment: Yes. I have several migrations. This is the only one throwing an error.

Comment: Can you edit your post with the migration code?

Comment: Done. Edited my original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the `DELIMITER` command. This command is intended to use just in MySQL Client. So, you can't use it in Laravel.

Take a time to read this post: [Creating MYSQL Procedure in Laravel 4 Migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18379137/creating-mysql-procedure-in-laravel-4-migrations)

It's a problem very similar to yours.